# Calculating per-face normal for a simple triangle

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I've been messing around with some 3D stuff (more specifically with LibGdx, but it doesn't matter for this question) and recently I've found a problem trying to calculate per-face normal for a simple triangle.
The triangle mesh that I've generated has the following vertices (also shown in the link below):

`v0 = [3 , 0 , 0]       //X, Y, Z`
`v1 = [1.49 , 0.86 , 0] //X, Y, Z`
`v2 = [3 , 0 , -1]      //X, Y, Z`

For calculating the face normal for that triangle mesh I've used a function that I was able to find in many tutorial/examples websites (with minor modifications):

```
private Vector3 calculateNormal(float vX1, float vY1, float vZ1,
                                float vX2, float vY2, float vZ2,
                                float vX3, float vY3, float vZ3) {

        Vector3 edge1 = new Vector3(vX1, vY1, vZ1).sub(vX2, vY2, vZ2);
        Vector3 edge2 = new Vector3(vX2, vY2, vZ2).sub(vX3, vY3, vZ3);

        Vector3 crsProd = edge1.crs(edge2); // Cross product between edge1 and edge2

        Vector3 normal = crsProd.nor(); // Normalization of the vector

        return normal;
}
```

After passing the values of the 3 vertices that formed the triangle into this method, I got the following as a result:

`[-0.49, -0.86, 0.0]`

[Representation of the Triangle Mesh and the Normal Vector (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk7WA.png)

**Problem 1:**
From what I have read, I don't think that the values of the calculated normal for that triangle are correct. My guess is that the normal should be positioned somewhere where it is perpendicular to the center of the triangle (X should be positive and Z should have a negative value).

**Problem 2:**
After calculating the per-face normal for the triangle, should all vertices of the triangle have the same per-face normal values, like so:

`verticesArr[v0Idx + 0] = 3; //Position`
`verticesArr[v0Idx + 1] = 0; //Position`
`verticesArr[v0Idx + 2] = 0; //Position`
`verticesArr[v0Idx + 3] = -0.49; //NormalX`
`verticesArr[v0Idx + 4] = -0.86; //NormalY`
`verticesArr[v0Idx + 5] =     0; //NormalZ`

`verticesArr[v1Idx + 0] = 1.49; //Position`
`verticesArr[v1Idx + 1] = 0.86; //Position`
`verticesArr[v1Idx + 2] = 0; //Position`
`verticesArr[v1Idx + 3] = -0.49; //NormalX`
`verticesArr[v1Idx + 4] = -0.86; //NormalY`
`verticesArr[v1Idx + 5] =     0; //NormalZ`

`verticesArr[v2Idx + 0] = 3; //Position`
`verticesArr[v2Idx + 1] = 0; //Position`
`verticesArr[v2Idx + 2] = -1; //Position`
`verticesArr[v2Idx + 3] = -0.49; //NormalX`
`verticesArr[v2Idx + 4] = -0.86; //NormalY`
`verticesArr[v2Idx + 5] =     0; //NormalZ`

I ask this second question because I've seen tutorial and examples where is shown a different perpendicular normal vector for each one of the vertices of a triangle (for calculating per-face normals and not per-vertex normals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem 1** : Normals don't have positions. They are the orientation of the vector that is perpendicular to the plane created by the combination of the directions of any two vectors of your triangle.

**Problem 2** : All verticies of a triangle should have the same normal as they are part of the same plane, the plane of your triangle.

[image: Normal]

As you can see, the direction of the normal vector will be the same, where ever you are on the triangle.

Comment: I think I understand your answer. My mistake was to think of a Normal as a position vector. I still can't seem to "visualize" what the normal "is" for the triangle (specially for my triangle) but with your answer I think I can move forward. As for the second part of your answer, "All verticies of a triangle should have the same normal..", that only applies for per-face normals, right?

Comment: Normals can be user defined. A triangle's normals in it's corners are mathematically all the same, but when you draw a sphere, in order to make it look more sphere like, the normals at the corners of each small shape will be the same for each shape that touches one another, either being averaged, being read through a obj file or being calculated by the derivative formula of the specific volume. The point of this is to give the impression of continuity though shading with stuff like Phong shading.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**
You can imagine the normal as a segment having one end point at coords (0, 0, 0) and the other end point at the values you obtained, that's (-0.49, -0.86, 0.0). What is important about the normal is its direction (or orientation), and that doesn't depend on the position where you place it in the 3D space.

**Problem 2:**
Very probably those are not surface normals, but vertex normals. More info here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_normal